# OutlinedInput Border issue for Textfield in Flutter

Tags: android-studio, dart, user-interface, flutter-layout, textfield

I have used OutlinedInput Border decoration but when increase borderRadius space in between labelText and outline border also increases plz help as i am beginner in Flutter.

Images link:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1037ezMhxWYjPY7IfMv4w-nxaaE7c_HAN?usp=sharing

Here's is my code:

```
TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                  filled: true,
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(45),
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                  ),
                  labelText: 'Email',
                 ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

First, try using TextFormField instead. It has validation and other options that work better than TextField within a Form.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextFormField-class.html

The label has its own borders that are also affected by your borderRadius value. Instead of using BorderRadius.circular, try BorderRadius.only().

```
TextFormField(
   decoration: InputDecoration(
                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                  filled: true,
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius:  BorderRadius.only(
                                    topLeft: Radius.circular(5),
                                    topRight:  Radius.circular(45),
                                    bottomLeft:  Radius.circular(45),
                                    bottomRight:  Radius.circular(45),
                              ),,
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                  ),
                  labelText: 'Email',
                 ),
),
```

This will allow you to keep the pill shape on 3 of the 4 corners. Your topLeft will need to be adjusted according to your preference.

Comment: Sorry, it didn't worked out

Comment: Same result as previous. Thanks for your time